# In Horizontal listview RefreshIndicator didn't work

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOux2.jpg)On my project two portion of body. one is freeze horizontal axis another one vertical. When I tried to refresh whole page the vertical show the refresh indicator but the horizontal part didn't work.

```
Container(
        child: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () async => ref.read(reloadProvider.notifier).reload(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              /* Horizontal */
              SizedBox(...),
              ref.read(fetchRegularMeetingTaskProvider.notifier).isLoading
                  ? Column(...)
              /* Vertical */
                  : Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                               Expanded(
                                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: ListView.builder(...),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
```

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will reproduce the issue

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: Are you using  `ListView` as horizontal?

Comment: Yes like this way .. Sizedbox(child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: value.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,))

Comment: The question is are you providing enough height to scroll, If I am not wrong I can see only `SingleChildScrollView` scroll vertically and its child is scrolling horizontally

Comment: Also what are you using as list item